# Change Curl URL in Swagger UI

Tags: php, swagger, slim, swagger-ui, swagger-php

I'm developing a new API using Slim Framework (v3).
I'm trying to integrate this API with Swagger UI, but when I click "Try it" button, Swagger generates the following link.

Example link:

```
http://localhost/api/public/contact?param1=1&param2=2param3=3
```

It's correct if I don't use Slim, but a link for Slim API is like:

```
http://localhost/api/contact/1/2/3
```

What I want is that Swagger use a link to Slim API, how can I do to achieve that? I can't find a way to "translate" the link format.

I'm using Swagger-php for comments (annotations).

I hope you can help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple different options.

First Swagger-ui won't show that link unless it's defined somewhere (i.e the `basePath` attribute) or left *undefined*.  It sounds like there's something missing there.

Next, you can *always* override the `basePath` in your API like such:

`window.swaggerUi.api.setBasePath('/api');`

Which should take away the `/api/public` section.

It's a little difficult to debug without seeing your JSON or YAML swagger definition but those two techniques should get you over the hump.